# What should our elevator pitch be?

Tags: discussion

Once decided, it can be sliced and diced to form:

- the tagline the motto the blurb under
- the logo
- a convenience redirect
  “nickname” for the site
- perhaps eventually the domain name in some
  form

Comment: In days gone by smoke break would have been a great name for this... not many would get it today.

Comment: This is one of the [seven essential questions of site metas](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), according to Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5):

Considering an elevator pitch as a 15 second commercial for the site, I'd suggest something like this:

> In your lifetime, you may have a dozen jobs at most. With billions of jobs out there, chances are there are some gaps in your knowledge about the workplace. The Workplace aims to provide expert knowledge to help fill in those gaps. From interviewing (["How can I overcome 'years of experience' requirements?"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1478/how-can-i-overcome-years-of-experience-requirements-when-applying-to-positions)) to negotiation (["How should I determine a reasonable salary to ask for?"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-can-i-determine-a-reasonable-salary-to-ask-for)) and beyond, someone should be able to help shed light on your workplace issues.

Comment: Sounds good to me, although I got momentarily stuck on the 5 billion figure because I was wondering why the number wasn't 7 billion. It might be nice to remove it in order to help overanalytical people like me. :-)

Comment: @Thunderforge But if someone asks you why only 5 billion, you get to start up a conversation! (Babies and old people don't work usually, and there isn't full employment unfortunately).

Comment: I did realize eventually why the number was 5 billion, but it made my mind lose focus on Workplace Exchange for a while. If this were a 15 second commercial, I'd hate for people to miss several seconds of it because their mind is figuring out the number, which happens early on in the "commercial."

Comment: @Thunderforge perhaps this is better for you?

Comment: That'll do. Thanks for addressing my minor nitpick :-)

Answer (score -1):

How about:

> - Workplace.SE - Your place for non-localized, widely applicable questions that can be answered with facts that can be backed up with either an anecdote or hyperlink.

Answer (score -2):

Ideas for the tagline/mottot/blurb:

- Information you can put into practice.
- Expert information backed up by experience and research.
- Perspectives from all levels of working organizations.

The logo:

Anything that's not those annoying stock photos of business people shaking hands, or smiling for the camera while wearing a suit and tie.

Convenient nickname:

- "working"

Comment: +1 - No shaking hands for sure. Too cheesy.

Comment: http://haha-business.com/business.jpg You sure we can't use this as logo and tagline?